# Two questions about PHP Simple SAML by OneLogin

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

If anyone has experience with Simple SAML (PHP) https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml I would really appreciate your help.

First of all, I have got it working. My app is the Service Provider and it does indeed permit authentication from an external Identity Provider. Hurrah!

However I have two questions that have come up as part of that process:

1) My SP generates a metadata URL. If the client has *already* provided their IDP's details, then that code works fine. I can see that the php-saml code builds the settings object, which validates, and returns the metadata XML. All good.

*But* if the client requests that metadata URL (in order to configure my SP at their end, in their IDP, *first*) it reports an error:

**"Invalid array settings: idp_entityId_not_found, idp_sso_not_found, idp_cert_or_fingerprint_not_found_and_required"**

Obviously that exception is pretty self-explanatory: of course those details have indeed not been provided yet.

So my question is: in looking at the XML of the SP metadata, it doesn't return any of their IDP details, so why *can't* it generate the metadata without knowing those details?

The reason this is a concern is what if the IDP has the same issue at *their* end (ie **they** wouldn't have the SP's details, get the same error, and so neither can proceed)?!

2) As part of the settings array, it asks for a x509 certificate and a private key to sign requests. Currently I'm using my site's SSL certificate (my-domain.com). That all works fine.

But I see other SP let people download their certificate.

So I could let people download the x509 part of my certificate - the public bit, I assume. But I'm wondering if the certificate even needs to be linked to the domain used by the metadata/ACS URLs?

Or can it be any old certificate e.g. a self-signed one? What do you do?

Thanks! I'm so confused by this. Simple it is surely not.

Comment: Is there a quick start on how to set this situation up?  I want what you have! 
[First of all, I have got it working. My app is the Service Provider and it does indeed permit authentication from an external Identity Provider. Hurrah!]

Separately, if we want to allow login via another IdP - is this something that's glued together via the OneLogin panel?

Comment: How do you mean? You want to recreate the problem I had? Only you should not have that same issue I had, since as @smartin says they sorted that issue of splitting the settings. And as for allowing more than one ACS URL (more than one IdP) ... hmm. I don't know ... I only needed one, as it worked on the basis of one client <-> one IdP so did not need to explore it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the OneLogin SAML Toolkit.

Related to 1) we already have a request of split the settings validation and we will implement that soon in all the toolkits: https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml/issues/74

Related to 2)

SAML requires the x509 cert/key in order to sign/encrypt SAML elements.

- Some IdPs/SPs use the same x509 of the Apache/Nginx server to enable HTTPs (bought certs).
- Others use self signed certs, (you can create yours with that tool (https://www.samltool.com/self_signed_certs.php). I recommend when creating them to use the IdP/SP domain in order to be able to identify them later (but is not required by SAML). You can use old ones, but since you can generate them anytime is a good practice to have them linked to the domain and get them fresh, avoiding that others could share it in the past).

Comment: Perfect - you are just the man to talk to then :)

1) Great - like I say, it does work as it is, but it would be nice to have that extra flexibility if you can add that

2) Ah, I see. That makes sense. I have just gone ahead and generated a new key/cert using your tool since I'd prefer to use that to keep a clear separation between my paid-for nginx certificate and the one used by SAML. Just to clarify: that generated key/cert is fine for production use - rather than just for a test environment, yes?

Comment: one more question too I've just spotted. I see the private key generated starts with BEGIN PRIVATE KEY. However the one I was using before started with BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY. Is that a problem? Is it something to do with PEM encoding or something? Which one is the right one to use?

Comment: The key/cert is not stored on the server and is published under HTTPs so you should be fine. but OneLogin warnings to don't include it on production servers.

Comment: Feature 1) is now available on the master branch.

Comment: Perfect - thank you! That was quick. Did you also see my other question about the private key format?

Comment: Both BEGIN PRIVATE KEY and BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY are supported and you will not find any problem.